# Blank text boxes?

Tags: bug

When trying to ask a question on the main site, I found this wierd bug.

[image]

The text boxes appeard blank.

Also, I entered a title with under 15 characters, and did not get a message saying `Title must be at least 15 characters`

Also, I did not get the list of tags when I typed in a tag.

I was in in-private mode. Was this the issue? I have not encountered this before.

Comment: That's odd. Was it only LH, or other SE sites also?

Answer (score 4):

Those validations work because of javascript - turn it on (you could have mistakenly turned it off).